# How to set jetty.home in Ubuntu 16.04 for CKAN

Tags: jetty, ckan, jetty-8

I'm following the "Installing CKAN from source" guide. And in the step to start the jetty service: `sudo service jetty start`. But it doesn't work, it prints "Failed to start jetty.service: Unit jetty.service not found".

Now, if instead that command, I use: `sudo /etc/init.d/jetty8 start`, the server starts correctly.

So, my guess (not totally sure) is that the jetty.home is not set properly.

For what it's worth, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, running in virtualbox.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

P.S: If additional information is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu 16, just run `sudo systemctl unmask jetty8` then `sudo service jetty8 start`

Comment: This did it for me. Seems like something to do with Ubuntu 16.06, didn't face this problem in Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 0):

If `sudo /etc/init.d/jetty8 start` works then you should be able to use

```
sudo service jetty8 start
```

(note the use of `jetty8` instead of `jetty`).